# create a standalone py server application for mac

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

I have some code written in Python designed for Mac OS X - its a TCP server that runs until it gets halted. Any way of making it a standalone application that could be installed easily by a third party? I have seen pyinstaller but not sure about how to build it for something like this need. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to create an installer for OSX, or just asking how to create an installer for a program you wrote in OSX?

Comment: installer for a program I have written in OSX :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let it be a python script and add a small gui with it.

```
from Tkinter import *
import sys
master = Tk()    
def callback():
    master.destroy()
    sys.exit()    
b = Button(master, text="Click to close", command=callback)
b.pack()    
mainloop()
```

which will close the running application and you will not have to ctrl+c to close it.. 
and Tkinter comes with python default.

Comment: and if you want to distribute it, then you can use the pyinstaller so it will work on computer without python as well.. and yes it will create a single executable(windows) file that can be used anywhere..

Comment: also you can do it change the myscript.py to myscript.pyw so it will not show the console and will show just the gui..

Answer (score 0):

you can use [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), I've used it with windows and it works perfectly.

also is you compare other tools like this, pyinstaller is the best because it gives you the ability to create just a single installer instead of a package.

Comment: Know what the recipe for creating a app for OSX that is run-forever and has no interface? (i.e. a TCPServer)?

Comment: can you be a little bit more clear?? is this `pyinstaller` is something what you were asking???

Comment: OK so my script does this (for example):

    python myscript.py --argument1 True --argument2 False

And then it runs until you send Ctrl+C to kill the script. 

What I want to do is create a double clickable app that when run, runs the above command and is killed by hitting the x (close window - or Quit) command. Possible? I doubt it.. So I figured it may be a app that has to be called on the line command. Thing is apps don't get called like that on OSX right?


Hope that makes sense. Apologies for any confusion :)